# How to redirect to Home page (Default page) in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm inside a module named "Authentication". After successful login with this module I want my user to redirect to home page (default page).

I tried the following route paths. But didn't worked.

```
$redirect = '/' ;
//$redirect = '' ;
//$redirect = null ;

return $this->redirect()->toRoute($redirect);
```

It generate the following error

> Route with name "" not found

Home route is not defined in another module which i don't know. So how do i redirect to home page ?

Comment: Any errors? I *think* `toRoute()` expects a named route.

Comment: @kerbholz yes. it looks toRoute() expects a name. Updated the error message.

Comment: So in theory you should make/create/have a named route called `home` (or anything else) pointing to `/`. This named route can be accessed from anywhere using `->toRoute('home')`.

Comment: Since its in another module, i cant tell what it is. I'm looking for something like ->toHome() or something similar ?

Comment: `toRoute()` does indeed expect a **name** of a route. You can look this up in any modules' `*.config.php` file or after boostrapping of the application you can request the config via the ServiceManager (ie. use `$serviceLocator->get('config')` in any Factory when debugging). If you've started out using the Skeleton Application of ZF2 (or 3) and have kept the default config, by default the home page route is named `'home'` (default location: `/module/Application/config/module.config.php` of the top of my head). Thus, you could use: `$this->redirect()->toRoute('home')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can’t tell what is your home route name, you have at least two options:

1. Make it configurable — put home route name in your module/application config and retrieve it in the controller.
2. Just redirect to `/`:

   ```
   return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/');
   ```